# Vuex. How to render data after it has been received from API before component started

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm having some troubles with render data from Vuex. I am making api call before component mounted and gonna render answer in my for loop. But 'computed' hook triggered before data is returned and it is not rendered (rendering undefined). 
I'm looking something kinda resolve function in AngularJS or something similar.
Also google helped me to realize that in React the way of receiving async data is implemented via redux-saga. But i can't find any working example on Vue which one covered my issue.
P.S. I'm just started learning Vue so i may be wrong at some details, any advise will be helpful for me =)

```
    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="ua">Choose appropriate user-agent</label>
                        <select v-model="selectedUA" class="form-control" id="ua">
                            <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
                            <option v-for="option in uaOptions" :value.sync="option.ua">
                                {{ option.name }}
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
    <script>
        module.exports = {
        beforeMount() {
          this.$store.dispatch('proxyList')
        },
        computed: {
          proxyOptions() {
            return this.$store.state.proxies
          }
        }
      }
   </script>
```

uaOptions is data which one i wanna render after successfull api call.

this is actions.js

```
    const actions = {
  proxyList(context) {
    return api.get(appConfig.serverAddress + '/get-countries')
      .then((response) => context.commit('PROXIES_SUCCESS', response))
      .catch((error) => context.commit('PROXIES_FAILURE', error))
  }
}
```

This is mutation.js

```
const mutations = {
  [types.PROXIES_SUCCESS](state, payload) {
    state.proxies = payload
    state.proxyInitError = false
  },
  [types.PROXIES_FAILURE](state, payload) {
    state.proxies = payload
    state.proxyInitError = true
  }
}
```

Comment: created hook can be used to run code after an instance is created.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you are asking, but maybe you should try using v-if="someVariable" to make sure that the list is only rendered when someVariable is not 'undefined' so you can avoid the error message.